# Finding a bounded continuous function on $(0,1] \in \mathbb{R}$ that attains neither a max or min

Tags: real-analysis

I have found a function that is bounded and continuous on $(0,1]$ but I am having some difficulties proving that it does not attain a maximum or a minimum. The function I have is the following:

$$ f(x) = (1-x)\sin\dfrac{1}{x} $$

Intuitively I can see that there is no maximum or minimum because of the oscillations of the sin function, and because of the multiplication with $(1-x)$ I can see that the max and min get large as x approaches 0. The problem I have is proving that the function attains no maximum or minimum, so I was hoping I could get some insight to help me think about an approach to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously
$\vert f(x) \vert \lt 1$ for $x \in (0,1]$.

As $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 1$ where $x_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}}$, $f$ can't have a maximum in $(0,1]$.

Similar proof for the minimum with $y_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi - \frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Comment: Yeah I see that now. I appreciate the use of the $x_n$, big fan of mapping convergent sequences, it's one of my more favorite concepts that I have learned in analysis.